# Need to display a busy window on max with spinner

Tags: macos, nsalert, nsprogressindicator

I'm a new Mac programmer writing my first mac app, actually porting an existing iOS app to MAC.

The app does a lot of remote communication, so when the user kicks off an operation, I want to display a busy window (or message box, or NSAlert maybe), until the operation is completed, then dismiss it programmatically, or the user can click cancel to stop it.

The busy window prevents the user from doing anything until that operation is completed.

The busy window should have a progress spinner, some text, and a cancel button.

Its such a simple thing yet I'm having problems with it because I dont really know MAC programming, getting myself frustrated.

Can anybody offer suggestions, or already written code for it. I hope some code for this already exists because I cant believe I'm the only person in the world who needs things kind of busy window.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

http://www.developers-life.com/example-nspanel-with-nsprogressindicator.html

???

Source code is available, too (link at the end of the article).

You can just modify the NSPanel in Xcode and add a "Cancel" button that you connect to your cancel action.